# GEE toma el 'in' de las palabras del código como si fuera un operador

Tags: javascript

Resulta que puse el código y me sale este error:

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'type' in roi

Me toma el `in` de las palabras `Sentinel`, `Collection`, etc., como si fuera un operador.

¿Alguien sabe por qué puede ser?
Pongo el código para ser más específica:

```
var ROI: LinearRing, 5 vertices

// Load Sentinel-1 C-band SAR Ground Range collection (log scale, VV, descending)
var collectionVV = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
                     .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
                     .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')) 
                     .filterMetadata('resolution_meters', 'equals', 10)
                     .filterBounds('roi')
                     .select('VV');
print(collectionVV, 'Collection VV');
```

Comment: No es un problema con el codigo, seguro es un problema con el dato traido por la coleccion, puede ser que en esa coleccion guardes un array de otra informacion??, puede que por eso no funcione, porque tratas de usar "in" en un array, y no un object.

Comment: No me reconocia la variable porque la habia escrito distinta!! Muchas graciasss Riven!!!